# .bash_profile:95: unmatched '

Tags: bash

I am trying to reload bash_profile from the terminal, and I get this error.

```
/Users/myname/.bash_profile:95: unmatched '
```

The reload command is

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I want to reload my bash_profile since I edited it using this command.

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Any solution on how to reload bash_profile?

Comment: You have to fix this in `.bash_profile` itself: there's an unbalanced single quote on line 95.

Comment: Bash said `/Users/myname/.bash_profile:95: unmatched '` so the most sensible thing to do is to fix that error, don't you think?

Comment: Thanks. I started searching for the extra ' immediately after I see your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using correct command to reload.

The issue is that your `.bash_profile` is unable to run correctly, it is having some issues in parsing the settings you put in it.

Since, I don't see your `.bash_profile` in question, I assume you put an extra character or forgot to close some quote in `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Had an extra ' on one of the export commands.